# Spring form:checkbox jquery event handle

Tags: jquery, spring

I use jQuery 1.9 and Spring 3.1.2.
I have next code in jsp:

```
<form:checkbox path="phoneBankChannel" />
```

And I have next code in js:

```
function isCheckedBankChannel() {
    if ($('#phoneBankChannel').is(':checked')) {
          alert("show something");
    } else {
        alert("hide something");
    }
}
```

Problem that this approach does not work. It works only when I add id attribute to form:checkbox. Can anybody help me ?

Comment: can you share the generated html

Answer (score 0):

try with attribute selector

```
 $('input[path="phoneBankChannel"]').is(':checked')) {
 .....
```

Comment: yaa.. i was wondering the same thing when i wrote checkbox there :)... looked weird.. ;) ...anyways  i meant `input`